# Java 8 to Java 11 migration of RowSet (getting error)

Tags: java

When migrating our project to Java 11, we are getting this error related to our use of [`RowSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/RowSet.html) technology (see [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/rowset.html)).

> java: cannot access com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl
>
> class file for com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl not found.
>
> java: incompatible types: com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl cannot be
>   converted to java.sql.ResultSet

I came to know in Java 11, `com.sun` packages are not accessible.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use [`RowSetProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql.rowset/javax/sql/rowset/RowSetProvider.html) to get a factory.

```
RowSetFactory aFactory = RowSetProvider.newFactory();
CachedRowSet crs = aFactory.createCachedRowSet();
```

From the Javadoc:

> A factory API that enables applications to obtain a [`RowSetFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql.rowset/javax/sql/rowset/RowSetFactory.html) implementation that can be used to create different types of [`RowSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/RowSet.html) implementations.